# Emacs fullscreen on Mountain Lion without Toolbar

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-mountain-lion, fullscreen

The newest version (24.3) of Emacs.app includes support for Mountain Lion's fullscreen.  However, even after disabling the toolbar (tool-bar-mode 0), the space for the toolbar is not used by Emacs, it just remains blank until the menu is shown.  How do I get this space back for a more full fullscreen experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is a newer version of Emacs.app is required.  24.3, while the latest, is not the latest and greatest.  24.3.50 is available via a nightly build.  It solves the problem.