# How do I remove the Emacs toolbar in a maximized window on OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs

I hid the Emacs toolbar with `(tool-bar-mode -1)`, but the toolbar appears again when the window is maximized.

I'm using Emacs 24.3 (9.0) on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

How can I remove the Emacs toolbar in any window size?

Comment: Please try with a `.emacs` file containing **ONLY** the following entry and then report back with the results:  `(tool-bar-mode 0)`.  You want to rule out other possible explanations, so that is why you are using a virtually empty `.emacs` file to run your test.

Comment: Following the idea of @lawlist, you can run `emacs -Q` so it is loaded without the `.emacs` and then in the `*scratch` buffer do `C-x C-e` when the point is at the end of `(tool-bar-mode 0)`.

Comment: By maximized, do you mean full screen? I have also disabled `tool-bar-mode`, and Emacs.app shows a 18 pixel tall white area at the top of full screen windows. Do you mean that or does it also show the icons or something?

Comment: Thanks for your advises! At first I only disabled by `eval-last-sexp` the `(tool-bar-mode -1)`. But when I restarted Emacs, the toolbar is disabled with fullscreen mode also. I should have restart before I ask here. Sorry and Thanks.

Comment: And the mention above (I can't read his name.), There is a white space around 20px and there is another 20px white space that I don't need. Do you know how to remove the white space, or should I ask in another question?

Comment: I found the answer for it here. http://superuser.com/questions/597708/emacs-fullscreen-on-mountain-lion-without-toolbar